# how send-register works on mvvm light?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I know how to use/code sending and registering objects in mvvm light. This is not what I want to ask but I am curious what is happening behind the scenes? I was searching all over and I couldnt find a deep explanation. Is it like address pointing in the memory. objects are addressed somehow by type or? I mean how one class sends and others finds it just by indicating their type. Can somebody shed some lights here please or a link reference where I can read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below links will help you to understand how register/subscription  works in mvvm light.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

http://brentedwards.net/2010/04/13/roll-your-own-simple-message-bus-event-aggregator/

I guess Mvvm light also using similar implementation. You can see the mvvm light messenger code [here](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Messaging/Messenger.cs)

Hope it helps